# Restricting dynamic segments to certain values in React Router v6?

Tags: reactjs, localization, react-router-dom

The URL structure we're implementing has URLS like `mysite.com/en/some-page` where `en` is the language the page is translated into. A simplified example of my code would be:

```
<Router>
    <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<RedirectToLocale />} />
        <Route path="/:locale">
            <Route index element={<Home />} />
            <Route path="about" element={<About />} />
            <Route path="news" element={<News />} />
            <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
        </Route>
        <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
    </Routes>
</Router>
```

`RedirectToLocale` simply redirects someone to the appropriate locale if they hit the base page.

The issue is this shows the home page for `mysite.com/en` (good) and `mysite.com/asdf` (bad). The latter should be caught by `*` as an error.

Previous versions of React Router had some level of RegEx support for Dynamic Segments but it seems v6 does not. Is there a way I can limit `:locale` to only known good strings and let the normal `*` match catch anything else?

I'm hoping the answer isn't "hard-code all your locales"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally the answer is to hardcode the locales via layout routes, but if you want to render only a single layout route you can read and test the `locale` route path parameter in the layout component and redirect off the route if the parameter value is invalid.

Example testing for English|French locales:

```js
console.log(/en|fr/gi.test("de"));
console.log(/en|fr/gi.test("en"));
console.log(/en|fr/gi.test("fr"));
```

```
import { Navigate, Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const LocaleLayout = () => {
  const { locale } = useParams();
  const isValidLocale = /en|fr/gi.test(locale);
  return isValidLocale
    ? <Outlet />
    : <Navigate to="/" replace />;
};
```

...

```
<Router>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<RedirectToLocale />} />
    <Route path="/:locale" element={<LocaleLayout />}>
      <Route index element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="about" element={<About />} />
      <Route path="news" element={<News />} />
      <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
    </Route>
    <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
  </Routes>
</Router>
```

Comment: The logic for the redirect was a bit more complicated than this but it clued me in to a way of solving things. Thanks!

For anyone who comes across this, I'm doing the validation based on some context where I get the total list of locales from a server. So I wait for that to populate initially and use a useEffect to manage some of my redirection logic.

Comment: @dougoftheabaci Yes, doesn't sound much different than an implemented authentication check from a context/global state for route protection. [Same basic pattern](/a/66289280/8690857).